# Multiple different return types from the same function

Tags: c#, return-type

I wanted to return two different values from the same function, but it turns out you can only return 1, but there are others around it like using tuple and out parameters... I don't understand how to structure them and syntax is confusing. I tried several times to make it work, by trial and error, but every time the program doesn't even start. If you can show me a solution that would be much appreciated. I managed to return string[]cards, but now I need to understand how I can return int[] value from the same function

```
namespace Testing2._0
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string[] cards =  ShuffleCardSystem();
            Dealing(cards);
            Format();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static void Format ()
        {
          //Not important
        }


        }
        static string [] ShuffleCardSystem()
        {
            string[] ranks = new string[13] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K" };
            int rankCounter = 0;
            string []suits = new string[4] { "♠", "♣", "♦", "♥" };
            int suitsCounter = 0;
            int shuffle; string temp;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int[] value = new int[52];
            string numbers = string.Empty;
            int convert;
            string[]cards = new string[52];
            for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            {
                cards[i] = ranks[rankCounter] + suits[suitsCounter];
                rankCounter++;
                if (rankCounter == 13)
                {
                    rankCounter = 0;
                    suitsCounter += 1;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 51; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                    numbers= string.Empty;
                shuffle = rnd.Next(0, i);
                temp = cards[shuffle];
                cards[shuffle] = cards[i];
                cards[i] = temp;
                for (int position =0; position<cards[i].Length; position++)
                {
                    if (char.IsDigit(cards[i][position]))
                    {
                        numbers+=cards[i][position];
                        convert= Convert.ToInt32(numbers);
                        value[i]= convert;
                        if (value[i] ==1)
                        {
                            value [i]=11; 
                        }

                    }
                    if (cards[i].Any(char.IsLetter))
                    {
                        value[i] = 10;
                    }
                }
            }
            }

            return cards; // I want to return value

        }
        static void Dealing(string[] cards)
        {
           //other unrelated code...
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you return a class?

Comment: Try to return object array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Shuffled
{
public string[]cards{get;set;}
public int[] values{get;set;}
}
```

C# is an object-oriented language. It's very common to return an object that contains your data from functions.

```
static Shuffled ShuffleCardSystem()
```

Comment: Sorry, don't quite understand this concept, so i created a new class called shuffled then change the "string [] ShuffleCardSystem()" to "static Shuffled ShuffleCardSystem()" ? If that is the case then what do i do with the string[]cards declaration in my Main function? @AD.Net